# FIWARE - IDAS :Which IoT-Agents protocol should I choose?

Tags: iot, fiware, agent, fiware-orion

I want an Iot Agents that support Interaction models: Active Attributes.
My choice is OMA LWM2M, I am wondering whether there is another choice is same or better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMA LWM2M is also supported by the OneM2M standard so it is a good option.
However, a simpler one might be the UL2.0 over HTTP or MQTT.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.